# Why do conversions of different number formats not work as expected in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion

This works:

```
[IN]  int(str(8))
[OUT] 8
```

This does not work:

```
[IN]  int(bin(8))
[OUT] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b1000'

[IN]  int(hex(8))
[OUT] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x8'
```

This is also weird:

```
[IN]  bin(str(8))
[OUT] TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 
# What are you telling me, Python?! You just did it with int()!
```

But:

```
[IN]  float(str(8))
[OUT] 8.0
```

Even worse:

```
[IN]  int(8.5)
[OUT] 8
[IN]  int(str(8.5))
[OUT] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.5'
[IN]  float(str(8.5))
[OUT] 8.5           # IT WORKS??!
```

This makes `int(some_string)` a bad choice and instead `int(float(some_string))` should be preferred!

Or:

```
[IN]  hex(hex(8))
[OUT] TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Bad design: A method that converts an object to the type it belongs to should always accept its own type as a valid input. (I know the type is `str`, but anyway).

```
[IN]  complex(str(complex(8)))
[OUT] (8+0j)
# What are the rules again?
[IN]  int(abs(complex(str(8.5))))
[OUT] 8
# OK... I guess?
```

This seems very anti-Pythonic to me. Is there a design reason why these very intuitive conversions  don't work, or is it simply something that noone thought about and that needs to be improved? Or maybe I'm doing it the wrong way?

The only solution I found is

```
[IN]  eval(hex(8))
[OUT] 8
[IN]  eval(bin(8))
[OUT] 8
```

Comment: All seems perfectly normal. And as always, don't use `eval`, it is evil.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Whatever you define as "normal". This is Python after all!

Comment: You're expecting way, way more implicit conversion than Python does. Python prefers to be more explicit about this kind of thing.

Comment: But `bin(..)` and `hex(..)` are not datatypes. It simply is the binary and hexadecimal *notation* of that number... And how do you expect an `int` to be 8.5?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I know that bin() and hex() return a string. I wrote it in my question! And why should an int not be 8?

Comment: @uzumaki: but what would be the result of `bin('8')`? You expect it to be the same like `bin(8)`? Then what should be the `bin('bla bla bla')`?

Comment: If you want tons of error-prone implicit conversions everywhere, try Javascript or PHP.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem bin('8') should be the same as bin(int('8')). Only you know what bin('bla bla bla') is.

Comment: @uzumaki: but a string with a character `'8'` is not the same as the number `8`...

Comment: [Python's philososophy](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states "Explicit is better than implicit." Allowing `bin('8')` would require an implicit conversion.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem int('8') works. float('8') works. complex('8') works. So why shouldn't bin('8') or hex('8') work?

Comment: @uzumaki: as said before, because there is no inherent binary/hexadecimal representation for a string. It has representations like ASCII, UTF-8, Unicode, etc. It's like asking what the best monoid is, there is no a priori a selected one.

Comment: They can!  `def bin(whatever): if type(whatever) == string: etc etc`  You can write your own bin!

Comment: @uzumaki: `int('8')`, `float('8')` and `complex('8')` are (string representation of number) -> (number). `bin` and `hex` go (number) -> (string representation of number). You're trying to go (string representation of number) -> (different string representation of number), which isn't bin or hex's job. That's two conversions, one to decide what number the first string represents and one to get the new string representation.

Comment: Similarly, `int('8.5')` would be two conversions, one to decide what number `'8.5'` represents and one to truncate that number. Python won't do those two conversions unless you tell it to do two conversions.

Comment: It sounds like you might prefer [Perl](https://www.perl.org/).

Comment: This is fun!  Pile on @uzumaki day!  Truthfully, I didn't know complex(), bin() or hex() existed before this post.  So thanks, @uzumaki!

Answer (score 1):

The `int` constructor accepts a second argument to specify the base that a first string argument should be interpreted in. So your examples with `bin` and `hex` would work if you specified base `2` and `16` respectively. Python won't use the prefix on the number to guess the base for you unless you specify the "special" base `0`, which tells it to use the prefix to determine the base (otherwise appropriate prefixes are ignored and invalid ones cause exceptions). You can see that your issue is base related in the exception message, which specifically say the input values are not valid "for int() with base 10".

Similarly, Python won't implicitly truncate the fractional part of the string representation of a decimal value when creating an `int`. If you want to convert the string `"8.5"` to the integer `8`, you need to first parse the string to a float (with e.g. `val = float("8.5")`), then convert the value to an integer, discarding the fractional part (e.g. `int_val = int(val)`). You can of course chain them together (`int(float("8.5"))`), but Python won't ever do the combined operation automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a few fundamental misunderstandings here.  Lets go through a couple of the various functions you called out.  To start, lets look at `int`, and just try running `help`:

```
>>> help(int)
class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> int or long
 |  int(x, base=10) -> int or long
 |  
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is floating point, the conversion truncates towards zero.
 |  If x is outside the integer range, the function returns a long instead.
 |  
 |  If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
 |  Unicode object representing an integer literal in the given base.  The
 |  literal can be preceded by '+' or '-' and be surrounded by whitespace.
 |  The base defaults to 10.  Valid bases are 0 and 2-36.  Base 0 means to
 |  interpret the base from the string as an integer literal.
 |  >>> int('0b100', base=0)
 |  4
```

So `int(foo)` converts a string or number-type to an integer.  Seems reasonable.

```
>>> help(bin)
bin(...)
    bin(number) -> string

    Return the binary representation of an integer or long integer.
```

And here `bin(foo)` converts an integer to a string (e.g.: `"0b1010111"`)

Note that numbers in python are not `bin` or `hex` - those are bases.  They are **numbers**, and can be stored as an `int`, `float`, `long`, etc.  As a convenience to you the interpreter is happy to convert things like `1e6`, `21.4`, `0x12`, `0777` into their respective number equivalent, but that doesn't mean that the numbers have "string" as a native format, or the base of the number that the representation was given is stored along with the value.

The root of your confusion seems to be that you are taking `str` as a first class object - perhaps because that is what is used to type code?  The sentence (emphasis mine):

> Bad design: A method that converts an object to the type it belongs to should always accept its own type as a valid input. **(I know the type is str, but anyway)**.

Highlights this root.

To assume that `bin` would work for a string as well as an integer in python is somewhat silly, in the same way the expecting `int("the smallest prime larger than the population of florida")` is a bit silly.  They do what they are documented to do.

A loose language such as Wolfram Alpha might take these in stride, while a strict language like Haskell might laugh at the concept of even allowing multiple types and argument counts for the same function.

For completeness:

- `bin('8')`, `hex('0x8')`  # Correctly rejects a non-integer
- `int('0b1000')`, `int('0x8')`, `int('8.5')`  # Correctly rejects non-integer string
- `int('0b1000', base=0)`, `int('0x8', base=0)`  # Correctly performs slower interpretation depending on the string base
- `int('8.5', base=0)`  # Still correctly rejects non-integer string
- `int(8.5)`  # Correctly 'truncates a floating point towards 0'
- `eval(foo)`  # Please avoid use of eval, there are no common correct applications of this function

Highlighting this comment from Alan Leuthard:

> There are two different int() functions. One accepts a single input
>   and is extremely fast. The other is slower and allows casting to
>   different bases. Efficiency of an often used built-in function is the
>   reason for the lack of features you want.

Comment: More or less you just explained how these functions are implemented. My question was WHY they were implemented this way. "int('0b1000'), int('0x8'), int('8.5') # Correctly rejects non-integer string" As others have pointed out it CORRECTLY accepts non-integer strings, when providing the base. Your argument fails.

Comment: There are two different int() functions.  One accepts a single input and is extremely fast.  The other is slower and allows casting to different bases.  Efficiency of an often used built-in function is the reason for the lack of features you want.

Comment: @uzumaki Yes, it accepts non-integer strings _when explicitly given the base of the number_. The conversion is no longer implicit, it's explicit.

Comment: @AlanLeuthard I have edited your note into my response, let me know if this bothers you

Answer (score 0):

Let's see here:

> This works:
>
> ```
> [IN]  int(str(8))
> [OUT] 8 This does not work:
>
> [IN]  int(bin(8))
> [OUT] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0b1000'
>
> [IN]  int(hex(8))
> [OUT] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0x8'
> ```

There are no built-in hexadeximal or binary objects, only the string representations created by the built-in functions.  You can always create them, if you'd like.  So you're not casting from an int to a bin to an int, you're casting from a str to an int.  Expecting the built-in int() function to recognize every string representation of a number is a bit much.

EDIT: I stand corrected, there's a second input to put a base.  So `int(hex(8), 16)` would give you 8 and `int(bin(8), 2)` would also give you 8.  Fancy that! Those Pythonistas think of everything...and now I learn a bit too!

> This is also weird:
>
> ```
> [IN]  bin(str(8))
> [OUT] TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 
> # What are you telling me, Python?! You just did it with int()!
> ```

bin() doesn't accept strings.  Only integers.  Write your own if you need it.  It also only outputs a formatted string.

> But:
>
> ```
> [IN]  float(str(8))
> [OUT] 8.0
> ```

Yeah.  Float accepts string representations of integers.  bin() isn't as useful or as ubiquitous as float()

> Even worse:
>
> ```
> [IN]  int(8.5)
> [OUT] 8
> [IN]  int(str(8.5))
> [OUT] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '8.5'
> [IN]  float(str(8.5))
> [OUT] 8.5           # IT WORKS??!
> ```
>
> This makes `int(some_string)` a bad choice and instead `int(float(some_string))` should be preferred!

Double casting (from a string to a float) in a single function is a bit much to ask.  It requires int() to accept way too many inputs for a built-in function.  The string has to be a representation of an int already.  Simple and clear.  And yes, if your string might be a float, cast it to a float first, then into an int.  Not really much more work.  You could always catch the exception, too!

> Or:
>
> ```
> [IN]  hex(hex(8))
> [OUT] TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer Bad design: A method that converts an object to the type it belongs to
> ```
>
> should always accept its own type as a valid input. (I know the type
>   is `str`, but anyway).

hex() creates a string.  You answered your own question.  If you want a Hex object, I believe there are several packages that implement them.

> ```
> [IN]  complex(str(complex(8)))
> [OUT] (8+0j)
> # What are the rules again?
> [IN]  int(abs(complex(str(8.5))))
> [OUT] 8
> # OK... I guess?
> ```

complex() takes a string representation of a complex as a valid input.  That doesn't seem strange at all.  Nor is it strange that int takes the absolute value of a complex (since all it has to do is ignore the imaginary part).  Here, we see the effect of having an actual object implemented.  Complex numbers are fully implemented in the built-in environment.  Hex and Bin are not.

> This seems very anti-Pythonic to me. Is there a design reason why
>   these very intuitive conversions  don't work, or is it simply
>   something that noone thought about and that needs to be improved? Or
>   maybe I'm doing it the wrong way?
>
> The only solution I found is
>
> ```
> [IN]  eval(hex(8))
> [OUT] 8
> [IN]  eval(bin(8))
> [OUT] 8
> ```

You can argue that Hex and Bin should be fully implemented objects in the built-in environment.  But, currently, they aren't.  Find a package that does it, or write your own objects.

Comment: More or less you just explained how these functions are implemented. Writing things like "complex() takes a string representation of a complex as a valid input." really doesn't qualify as part of an answer at all. I was just trying to point out the different rules that have to be followed for every function. For example as int() excepts a value of 8.5 it is very counter intuitive that it doesn't accept the string representation '8.5' while the function float() does. Saying that because '8.5' is not an integer it would require too many inputs is completely bogus!

Comment: @uzumaki It's more obvious that a number is being converted to a float and then rounded if you have to use `int(float('8.5'))`. The extra few characters are worth it to prevent headaches down the road when you have a hard-to-track-down bug because of something like this.

Comment: So bogus!  Totally agree.  I say int should accept 'eight' as an input as well!